# W3 XML demo not validating - No matching global declaration available for the validation root

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I am trying to learn how to use extensions in xml schema. I took this example (Example 2 from here: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_extension.asp)

### myschema.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="employee" type="fullpersoninfo"/>

<xs:complexType name="personinfo">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="fullpersoninfo">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="personinfo">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType> 

</xs:schema>
```

and made a demo xml data file:

### data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<personinfo>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
</personinfo>
```

But when I try to validate it, I get:

```
xmllint --schema myschema.xsd data.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<personinfo>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
</personinfo>
data.xml:3: element personinfo: Schemas validity error : Element 'personinfo': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
data.xml fails to validate
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML file has a root element named `personinfo` but your schema doesn't contain a declaration for an element with that name.  It contains a declaration of a *type* called `personinfo` but the only *element* declaration is for `employee` (of type `fullpersoninfo`).

An example XML file that validates against the current schema would be something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<employee>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
    <address>5 Somewhere Street</address>
    <city>Anytown</city>
    <country>Australia</country>
</employee>
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was clearly missing the distinction between a type and an element.